# accessing an inner value of a "hash of hashes" by reference

Tags: perl

I have an Hash of Hashes, that I'm sending to a subroutin and i want to access its keys, and its values (both keys and value).

I have:

```
sub replace_sub {
    my ( $result_dir, $FilesHash ) = @_;
    foreach my $file ( keys %{$FilesHash} ) {
        open( INPUT_FILE, "$result_dir/$file" ) or die "Can't create output file\n";
        my @LINES = <INPUT_FILE>;
        open( my $output_file, ">", "$result_dir/$file" ) or die "Can't create output file\n";
        foreach my $myline ( keys %{ $FilesHash{$file} } ) {
            for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#LINES; $i += 1 ) {
                if ( $LINES[$i] =~ m/$myline/ ) {
                    my $line = $LINES[$i];
                    $LINES[$i] =~ s/\Q$line\E/\/\/  $line  $FilesHash{$file}{$myline}\n/g;
                }
            }
        }
        print $output_file @LINES;
        close(INPUT_FILE);
        close($output_file);
    }
}
```

but I cant figure how to access the values of the inner hashes, 
the code line that is trying to do that is:

```
my $myline ( keys %{ $FilesHash{$file} } )
```

and

```
$LINES[$i] =~ s/\Q$line\E/\/\/  $line  $FilesHash{$file}{$myline}\n/g;
```

how can I access them?

I'm planning on calling the subroutin that way:

```
replace_sub ($result_dir, \%Hash)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`use strict;` would tell you that there is no such thing as `%FilesHash` as `$FilesHash` is hashref, thus

```
$FilesHash{$file}
```

should be replaced with

```
$FilesHash->{$file}
```

Comment: if I understand it correctly, at your example $v2 will hold the inner value?
for example: `my %Hash = ( "external_key" => { "inner_key" => "inner_value", }, ); ` than $v2 = "inner_value" ?

Comment: @user3350919 yes, and in your case that is `$FilesHash->{$file}{$myline}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [each()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) when iterating over a hash:

```
while ( ( $key1, $value1 ) = each %{$FilesHash} ) {
    while ( ( $key2, $value2 ) = each %{$value1} ) {
        print "[$key1] $key2 => $value2\n";
    }
}
```

N.b. you may find this more readable but not everyone considers this 'good' practice (read comment @tobyink)

Comment: A lot of very smart programmers are now recommending [avoiding `each`](http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html) because it can result in fairly confusing action-at-a-distance problems. `each` is fast, but looping over `keys` can be safer. Personally I'd loop over `keys`, and only consider `each` for particular isolated loops that have proven to be bottlenecks when benchmarking, and even then, only when it can be demonstrated to be safe.